# How to maximize likelihood function

Tags: multivariate-analysis, likelihood

Imagine I have a set of measures and I want to model my data as a multivariate normal distribution. For every measure I have a different mean vector and covariance matrix. So, how can I be sure about what are the parameters that fit better my data? Do I have to compute the log-likelihood for every set of parameters and see when this is minimum?

Answer (score 1):

You *can't* compute log-likelihood's for each pair of $(\mu, \Sigma)$ since both of those parameters are real numbers, so both can take infinite number of possible values (even if you had multiple discrete-valued parameters, it might not be possible to use brute-force search in a limited time). Assuming that you don't have a [closed form solution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70848/what-does-a-closed-form-solution-mean) for finding the optimal parameters, otherwise you would need an optimizer (see [Wikipedia article on optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization)), i.e. a black-box function that takes your function and returns an optimal set of parameters.

Comment: I have a set of multiple measures and I want to model this data as multidimensional gaussian, but the problem arises because I don't know what mean and covariance matrix use. Is there any function in matlab that could do this?

Comment: @Moltimor I don't know Matlab and such question would be off-topic in here, but I'm sure that Matlab has to have implemented optimization algorithms (otherwise it would be useless for most of the applications).