# Various Methods to Calculate Linear Regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I have just started learning Machine Learning and one of the very first topics that I have encountered in this venture is Simple Linear Regression. From Andrew Ng's course, I have learned to perform simple linear regression using gradient descent using the loss function. But recently I was watching this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSQ2plMtbLc)  where the professor gives an equation to find the slope and the interception in 1 step.

Say if my equation is this $y=a_1 x + a_0$

Then, we can calculate $a_1$ and $a_0$ by these equations

$a_1$=$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i y_i  – \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i}{n\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}^2 -(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)^2 }$

$a_0$=$\bar{y}-a_1 \bar{x}$

wherer $\bar{y}=$ $mean$ $of$ $y$ and $\bar{x}=$ $mean$ $of$ $x$

**Question 1:**
Since this method involves no iteration that is needed to compute slope and intercept in the case of Gradient Descent, isn't it better than gradient descent?

**Question 2:**
And what is the name of this method?

Comment: Answer to 2: *Ordinary Least Squares,* aka OLS.  Nobody uses gradient descent for OLS: the point is to illustrate and teach gradient descent with in this extremely well-understood setting.

Comment: In multiple linear regression Andrew Ng has taught a method known as Normal Equation for solving multiple linear regression. Cant we OLS for Multiple linear regression as well and have a direct formula to derive the values ?

Comment: As you might imagine, this is a well-discussed topic: see the top-voted posts on regression and multiple regression here.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/343069/why-not-use-the-normal-equations-to-find-simple-least-squares-coefficients

I have seen this link and it is saying that OLS itself is Normal Equation, I am really confused here

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+normal+equations.  For an account to bridge your algebraic notation to the matrix notation needed for multiple regression, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352130.  If that's not perfectly clear, see the explicit example for two regressors at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/196807.