# LinearRegression in Pytorch and sklearn, what is the differnece?

Tags: regression, scikit-learn

I am currently implementing Linear Regression in Pytorch and sklearn and I get two different Mean squared error (MSE) values for both. MSE is lower for Pytorch Linear Regression.

**Wanted to ask what the difference between linear regression in PyTorch and sklearn?**
I understand for that Pytorch the workflow follows:

1. Create LinearRegression class
2. Define model from this LinearRegression class
3. MSE: Mean Squared error
4. Optimization (SGD: stochastic gradietnt descent)
5. Backpropagation
6. Prediction

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference is that linear regression usually [is not fitted using gradient descent](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160179/do-we-need-gradient-descent-to-find-the-coefficients-of-a-linear-regression-mode). Gradient descent is inferior and inefficient for this problem.

From [scikit-learn’s documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html)

> From the implementation point of view, this is just plain Ordinary Least Squares (scipy.linalg.lstsq) or Non Negative Least Squares (scipy.optimize.nnls) wrapped as a predictor object.

So instead gradient descent [use least squares in PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.lstsq.html).

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: @wowewow if it answers your question you can mark it as solved.

Comment: You mentioned gradient descent is inferior why is that the case? Additionally, you mentioned that Pytorch use least squares and from my understanding Pytorch uses GD to minimize least squares is this not the same with scikit learn where it try to minimize the least squares as well ?

Comment: @wowewow No, ordinary least squares is a different algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares, the linked thread goes into more details.