# Why we use MSE in linear regression gradient descent rather than RSS?

Tags: regression, gradient-descent

Why in linear regression, when we use gradient descent, the cost function is MSE rather than RSS?

Comment: Usually, [we do not use gradient descent for linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160179/do-we-need-gradient-descent-to-find-the-coefficients-of-a-linear-regression-mode). Even if you would like to use it, nothing prohibits you from using the sum of squares instead of mean, because they differ only by the $1/N$ constant and lead to exactly the same results, as discussed in the thread linked as a duplicate of yours.